# How do I get the size for a UICollectionView cell when layoutSubviews hasn't been called

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create a UICollectionView where the cells are varied sizes based on the contents within them and how those contents play with the constraints set on them. Basically, I need to examine the frame size but this size isn't updated on the cell until after the subviews have been laid out.  Unfortunately, this isn't done until the view is attached to the window hierarchy it seems.  I can't find any series of calls to trigger this without adding it to the window hierarchy, yet I don't *want* to add it to the hierarchy except through this UICollectionView. And, of course, the collection view wants the size of it before it requests and adds the cell.

I can't get to size without adding it to the window hierarchy (I think), and I can't get it added to the window hierarchy (i.e. the collection view) without having the size.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Just call these on the cell, and it should act as though it was added to the view hierarchy:

```
setNeedsLayout()
layoutIfNeeded()
```